# Isomorphism from ring to ring. Exercise from General Topology (J. Kelley)

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

I tried Exercise K from chapter 2 of General Topology by Kelley. Is this enough to show isomorphism between Boolean rings? This is part (d).

> Let $X$ be a set and let $\Bbb Z_2^x$ be the family of all functions on $X$ to  $\Bbb Z_2$ , Define addition and multiplication of functions pointwise:
>
> - $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$, and
> - $(f \cdot g) (x) = f(x) \cdot g(x)$.
>   Then $(\Bbb Z_2^x ,+,\cdot)$ is a Boolean ring with unit and is isomorphic to $(\mathcal a =\mathcal P(X),\Delta, \bigcap)$.

*Assume $(\mathcal a =\mathcal P(X),\Delta, \bigcap)$ is Boolean ring (followed from previous exercise).*

*Proof.* Observe that any function of $\Bbb Z_2^x$ has value of either $0$ or $1$.
So let $f,g\in \Bbb Z_2^x$, then for any $x\in X$ sum of the functions and multiplication is in $\{0,1\}$ for any $x\in X$:

- If $f(x)=0$ then $f(x)+f(x)=0+0=0,$
- if $f(x)=1$ then $f(x)+f(x)=1+1=2 \underbrace{=}_{\text{(mod 2)}}0$.

So in all cases, the addition satisfies definition of Boolean ring, which is $r+r=0 \quad \forall r\in R$.

Likewise with multiplication in Bool. ring: $r\cdot r=r$. If $f(x)=0$, then $0\cdot 0=0=f(x)$, and $1\cdot 1=1$ for $f(x)=1$.

Now to show isomorphism between $(\Bbb Z_2^x ,+,\cdot)$ and $(\mathcal a,\Delta, \bigcap)$ let

$$\varphi: \Bbb Z_2^x \to \mathcal a.$$

Then $\forall f\in \Bbb Z_2^x$:

$\begin{align}   
\bullet \varphi(f(x)+f(x))=\varphi(0)=\emptyset&=A\Delta A \\
 &=\varphi(f(x)) \Delta \varphi(f(x)),\\   
\bullet \varphi(f(x)\cdot f(x))= \varphi(f(x))=A&=A\bigcap A\\
&=\varphi(f(x))\bigcap \varphi(f(x)) \\
&= \varphi(f(x)\cdot f(x)). \square
\end{align}$

Comment: Let $\phi$? **Define** $\phi$, *that*'s the job to do.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma In my mind I thouhgt somehting like 'Let $\varphi$ be function s.t. $\varphi: \Bbb Z_2^x \to \mathcal a$.

Comment: You have to show an isomorphism exists not fantasize about one...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Is there a 'general' way for showing it? I have only came across this term and a definition as written in OP. But I see you are using inverse function in your post below...

Comment: No, you have to think and be creative, as often is the case in mathematics. I use inverse images not an inverse function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $\Bbb Z_2^X$ is actually a Boolean ring looks OK.

The second part of the proof consists of actually specifying the isomorphism and checking it. I don't see you define $\phi$ at all, just state the properties it should have.

So define $\phi: \Bbb Z_2^X \to \mathscr{P}(X)$ by $$\phi(f) = f^{-1}[\{1\}] =\{x \in X: f(x)=1\} \in \mathscr{P}(X) \text{ for } f \in \Bbb Z_2^X$$

One directly checks that $\phi(\overline{0}) = \emptyset$ and $\phi(\overline{1})=X$.

Then note that $x \in \phi(fg)$ iff $f\cdot g(x)=1$ iff $f(x)=1 \land g(x)=1$ iff $x \in \phi(f) \cap \phi(g)$

so that $\phi(fg)=\phi(f) \cap \phi(g)$ as sets.

Also $x \in \phi(f+g)$ iff $(f+g)(x)=1$ iff $f(x)+g(x)=1$ iff *exactly one* of $\{f(x), g(x)\}$ is $1$ iff $x$ is in *exactly one* of $\phi(f)$ or $\phi(g)$ iff $x \in \phi(f) \Delta \phi(g)$

so that $\phi(f+g)=\phi(f) \Delta \phi(g)$ as sets as well.

This shows that $\phi$ preserves ring operations, it finally remains to show that $\phi$ is a bijection between $\Bbb Z_2^X$ and $\mathscr{P}(X)$, do you see why this holds?

Comment: It is bijection, because for each member of $\mathcal P(X)$ we can pick a function from $\Bbb Z_2^x$ with properties of Bool. ring, and for any two functions there are distinct members of the powerset which satisfy operations of Bool. ring ?

Comment: @flowian The bijection part is pure set theory, nothing to do with Boolean rings.

Comment: So, for each member of the powerset there is a function from the modulo set, and for any two functions there are two distinct subsets of the $X$.

Comment: @flowian yes, that’s what needs showing. It’s not hard.

Comment: *proof* Since for each $x\in X \quad f(x) $ is in $\{0,1\}$ for any $f\in \Bbb Z_2^x$, there is a member from $\Bbb Z_2^x$ for each subset of $X$. For injection, since no two functions $f,g$ have exactly the same set of domain for 1 in the image(the domains may overlap), then there are values in domain of each function $x,z$ s.t. $f(x)=1=g(z)$, and $\varphi(f(x)) = x\neq z=\varphi(g(z)).$

Comment: @flowian No: For $A \in \mathscr{P}(X)$ define $\chi(A)=\begin{cases}1 & x \in A\\0 & x \notin A\end{cases}$ then $\phi(\chi_A)=A$ (show two inclusions). That shows onto. And if $\phi(f)=\phi(g)$ then let $x \in X$: if $f(x)=1$, $x \in \phi(f)$ so $x \in \phi(g)$ and $g(x)=1$. And if $f(x)=0$, $x \notin \phi(f)$ so $x \notin \phi(g)$ so $g(x)=0$. Ergo $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x$ and $f=g$. So $\phi$ is 1-1.

Comment: @flowian Really try to be more precise in this or Kelley will be hard going...

Comment: I feel humiliated for laziness, but value your pointing and solutions.